# How can I access value in sequence type?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

There are the following attributes in `client_output`

```
weights_delta = attr.ib()
client_weight = attr.ib()
model_output = attr.ib()
client_loss = attr.ib()
```

After that, I made the `client_output` in the form of a sequence through
`a = tff.federated_collect(client_output)` and `round_model_delta = tff.federated_map(selecting_fn,a)`in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/b13046fa47b2eab4f38c37fc41d7fba64f192bb1/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L131) . and I declared
`

```
@tff.tf_computation()  # append
def selecting_fn(a):
    #TODO
    return round_model_delta
```

in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/b13046fa47b2eab4f38c37fc41d7fba64f192bb1/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L107). In the process of averaging on the server, I want to average the `weights_delta` by selecting some of the clients with a small loss value. So I try to access it via `a.weights_delta` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tff.federated_collect` returns a `tff.SequenceType` placed at `tff.SERVER` which you can manipulate the same way as [for example](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/3c0852c5fef375198f5931ce31fd97f2df9c4d05/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L213) client dataset is usually handled in a method decorated by `tff.tf_computation`.

Note that you have to use the `tff.federated_collect` operator in the scope of a `tff.federated_computation`. What you probably want to do[*] is pass it into a `tff.tf_computation`, using the `tff.federated_map` operator. Once inside the `tff.tf_computation`, you can think of it as a `tf.data.Dataset` object and everything in the `tf.data` module is available.

[*] I am guessing. More detailed explanation of what you would like to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the `weight_delta` and `loss_sum` of each client?? I want to  select clients based on the `loss_sum` generated for each client and do `tff.federated_mean` using `weight_delta` of the selected clients.

Comment: Is there any way to find the mean of the `weight_delta` for only some of the clients??

Comment: I am not sure how to help more, since you refer to objects not in the question. What is `weights_delta`? `loss_sum`? Taking time to prepare a small self-contained example with a reproducible error would help. If not familiar yet, reading `tf.data` guides on the TF website could also help.